# Parsing Large XML files efficiently using R

Tags: r, xml, optimization, xml2

New here. I use R a lot, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with XML. I'm look for advice for efficiently looping through and aggregating large XML files (~200MB) from [here](https://www.grants.gov/web/grants/xml-extract.html). I have XML files with elements that look like this:

```
<OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0>
    <OpportunityID>134613</OpportunityID>
    <OpportunityTitle>Research Dissemination and Implementation Grants (R18)</OpportunityTitle>
    <OpportunityNumber>PAR-12-063</OpportunityNumber>
    ...
</OpportunitySynopsisDetail_1_0>
```

None of the sub-elements have children or attributes. The only complicating factor is that some elements can have multiple instances of a single child type.

I've already downloaded and parsed one file using the `xml2` package, and I have my `xml_nodeset`. I've also played around successfully with extracting data from subsets of the nodeset (i.e. the first 100 nodes). Here's an example of what I did to extract elements without an "ArchivedDate" sub-element:

```
for(i in c(1:100)){
    if (is.na(
        xml_child(nodeset[[i]],"d1:ArchiveDate",xml_ns(xmlfile)))){
        print(paste0("Entry ",i," is not archived."))
```

Here's the problem: if I replace 100 with `length(nodeset)` which is 56k+, this thing is gonna take forever to iterate through. Is there a better way to filter out and analyze xml elements without iterating through each and every one? Or is this just a limitation of the file format? The long term goal would be to get a very small subset of this file into a data frame.

Thanks!

Comment: The functions in xml2 are vectorized functions.  So one can pass the entire vector of nodes to the `xml_find_first` function without the need for a loop.  There are many examples here which demonstrate the technique.

Comment: Ah they're vectorized! That's what I missed. Thanks!